# Firebase - Accessing collection data within collection returns o.indexOf error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have functionality to retrieve firestore data from a document stored in a collection and render it to the client, however I also need to retrieve data from a document from a collection within the parent document and render this as well. I know that firestore stores data in a hierarchical manner but i'm getting this error:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: o.indexOf is not a function. (In 'o.indexOf("//")', 'o.indexOf' is undefined)

from the following code:

```
db.collection('tickets').get().then(snapshot => {
   snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
     renderTickets(doc);
     db.collection('tickets').doc(doc).collection('comments').get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        renderComments(doc);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Before I only had the following to only access the non-nested documents, which worked fine:

```
    db.collection('tickets').get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      renderTickets(doc); 
   });
});
```

My renderComments()/renderTickets() function (they are both the same):

```
function renderComments(doc) {

    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let comment = document.createElement('p');
    let name = document.createElement('p');
    let timestamp = document.createElement('p');

    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.docId);
    comment.textContent = "Description: " + doc.data().comment;
    name.textContent = "Type: " + doc.data().name;
    timestamp.textContent = "Priority: " + doc.data().timestamp;

    li.appendChild(comment);
    li.appendChild(name);
    li.appendChild(timestamp);

}
```

I need to render the comments under the associated ticket, and I don't want to access each doc/nested doc by hard coding it's name which is why I am trying to access the nested doc while I am inside the parent doc. Any ideas where i'm going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re passing a document reference to the `doc` method of the tickets collection reference, which expects a string. You don’t need to “start again” from the tickets collection, because you already have the document reference for the individual ticket, so you should just be able to do this:

```js
db.collection('tickets').get().then(snapshot => {
   snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
     renderTickets(doc);
     doc.ref.collection('comments').get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        renderComments(doc);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I understand why that should work but unfortunately it returns the following error: `Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: doc.collection is not a function. (In 'doc.collection('comments')', 'doc.collection' is undefined)`

Comment: @Jamie my bad! Updated answer should work for you (note `doc.ref.collection('comments')` instead of `doc.collection('comments')`)

`snapshot.docs` is an array of QueryDocumentSnapshot (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot). To get the sub-collection, you want a DocumentReference (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) which you get with `doc.ref`. Make sense?